# Javascript if document.referrer redirect to another URL

Tags: javascript

We are having issues getting the document.referrer url in our Javascript. We have a store and we want to prevent people from going from our shopping cart to a specific page. Meaning if they go from the shopping cart, hit the back button on the browser and the page before the shopping cart was a specific URL they need to skip that URL and we need to redirect to another page.
We want to specify the URL for the product/page to skip if the referring URL is the shopping cart.

I have tried doing this but seems not to work. Seems to fire on every single page no just the . I have it in the head of our Root.master page.  Here is my code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   if (pathname = "http://www.mywebstore.com/Page-we-want-to-skip-over.aspx") {
    if (document.referrer = "http://www.mywebstore.com/ShoppingCart.aspx") {
         window.location = 'http://www.mywebstore.com/Page-we-want-to-go-to-instead.aspx'
     }
   }
```

});

or we would like to skip back 2 pages. So we tried this too but it still fires on every single page, no just the page we want to prevent the back button action to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      var pathname = window.location.pathname;
       if (pathname = "http://www.mywebstore.com/Page-we-want-to-skip-over.aspx") {
        if (document.referrer = "http://www.mywebstore.com/ShoppingCart.aspx") {
             window.history.back(-2);
         }
       }
  });
```

Again both of these solutions look correct but they are not working.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like an attempt to hide a bad design.  Furthermore, JS won't solve your problem for users that have JS turned off, or for users in certain types of browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You are using assignment instead of equality

Change = to == in your tests.

Comment: Which part should have the == ? after the if(pathname == ...) or after document.referrer or both

Comment: Yes, inside both if() blocks, you do not ws to use a single =

Answer (score 2):

Using the back button doesn't change the referer in the way you want. e.g. a page sequence like:

```
A -> B -> C (backbutton) -> B
```

does not send 'C' as the referer when the user comes "back" to page B. The referer will be page A. Referers are set for 'forward' actions only, not 'back' actions.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to get page C and by pass B if the back button is pressed?

Comment: Not really. You'd have to introduce pure-javascript navigation which uses 'location.replace', effectively disabling the back button as many online banking sites do. The history object in browsers is heavily locked down and does not let one page view the history generated by another page, even if both pages are yours and coming from the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That really helps us in our issue. Kind of sucks but if that is the way it works. Not much we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Also, window.location.pathname does not include the domain.  So it should be:

```
if (pathname == "/Page-we-want-to-skip-over.aspx")
```

See the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) on `window.location`.

You should also keep in mind that the referrer is unreliable.  Some browsers or firewalls block it, and it can be forged.

Comment: What would be an alternative to referrer?

Comment: You could use sessions (on the web server) to track the user's page visits.